# Calling a function on click of button in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Could anyone suggest me a step by step procedure to call a function.
The function should take an input from the HTML page and query on the db.
I am able to connect to the DB and consider the input but could anyone help me out to call the function to query on the db ?
The function should be called when clicked on submit button.

Thanks in advance,
Sai

Comment: SO is not a community which offers step by step procedures. You need to do some research , try something first and then post a question if you are stuck with something

Answer (score 2):

You should use Ajax/XmlHTTPRequest for this. I'd suggest following a tutorial on Mootools or jQuery for this.

The general procedure will be to attach a click event to the button:

```
<button onclick="doMyThing()">Click here!</button>
```

Then inside the JS function `doMyThing` you set up a call using [Mootools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (click either for samples and documentation) to your serverside PHP script. In the success function of the request you can then process the results.

You could do the same without using a JS library, but you'd have to handle browser-specific intricacies of [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do make the HTML page a form. On submitting this form you will be taken to the action page . out here you could call your function that you want to be called. (This is if you are using a simple 2 page php setup).

But instead if you are using a php framework such as zend or cakephp etc . then you could prepare the url based on your controller and its corresponding function that you want to call and keep this url as the action attribute in your form. On submitting your function will be called